# How to display NO value instead of 01 Jan 1970 on date pull up

Tags: php, codeigniter

Got code from an old system but I can't modify it to show NO Expiry when date is Null or 0000-00-00 from database. Here is the code.

I tried IF function on $expiry_date but getting white screen

```
  function select_expiry_dates($set_select_name='expiry_date', $set_default_code='', $set_default_expiry_date='')
  {
    $ci =& get_instance();

    $ci->load->model('Expiry_dates_model');

    $expiry_dates = $ci->Expiry_dates_model->get_expiry_dates();

    if($expiry_dates->num_rows() > 0)
    {
      foreach ($expiry_dates->result() as $row)
      {
        $expiry_date        = $row->code .' ('. date('d M Y', strtotime($row->expiry_date)) .')';
        $default_value      = ($row->code == $set_default_code && $row->expiry_date == $set_default_expiry_date) ? TRUE : '';
        $set_select_option  = set_select($set_select_name, $expiry_date, $default_value);

        echo '<option value="'. $expiry_date .'" data-expiry="'. $expiry_date .'" data-expiry-rate="'. $row->rate .'" '. $set_select_option .'>'. $expiry_date .'</option>';
      }
    }

    return TRUE;
  }
```

I need expiry date ($expiry_dates) to Show NO Expiry or No date when being chosen from the database. Its currently showing as 01 Jan 1970 even if the data in the database is NULL.

Comment: "I tried IF function on $expiry_date but getting white screen" meaning you made a simple syntax error. Try again, and look for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Please check before display, is that date format is valid or not.

Here is a code to check:

```
function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d')
{
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    // The Y ( 4 digits year ) returns TRUE for any integer with any number of digits so changing the comparison from == to === fixes the issue.
    return $d && $d->format($format) === $date;
}
```

Results:

```
var_dump(validateDate('2018-15-01'));  // false
var_dump(validateDate('20184-16-01')); // false
var_dump(validateDate('2018-22-04'));  // true
```

Hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if($expiry_dates->num_rows() > 0)
{
  foreach ($expiry_dates->result() as $row)
  {
    if(is_null($row->expiry_date)){
        $date = 'No Date';
    }else{
         $date = $row->expiry_date;
    }
    //Use $date in the code...
  }
}
```